# Android RecyclerView stops scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**Problem**

I have a recyclerview that shows a list of songs loaded from an SQL database. My problem is when I scroll down it moves a few elements and then does the animation like it hit the bottom. I can then continue to scroll but it makes scrolling choppy and its very noticeable. The weird thing is it only happens when I'm scrolling down. If I scroll up I can go from the bottom to the top of the list smoothly. When scrolling down it recycles a few elements then abruptly stops and it doesn't seem to be a set amount before it stops. It also doesn't matter how fast I scroll, even when going slow it will do this.

I made a custom alphabet selector that allows to jump to specific parts in the list which works fine, but I disabled it to see if that was causing the issue but its not.

**Video**

The first couple scrolls are going down and you can see it stops with the "bottom of list" animation. I can then continue scrolling. The last scroll is going up where it slowly comes to a stop and doesn't show the "top of list" animation.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-Tr8DDGJCc&feature=youtu.be

**Code**

*Fragment*

```
public class LibraryFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView mTitle;

    private RecyclerView itemsView;
    private SideSelector selector;
    private LibraryListAdapter adapter;
    private AppDatabase mDatabase;
    private Song.ModeType mMode = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library, container, false);

        mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        mTitle.setText("LIBRARY");

        itemsView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.library_items);
        selector = (SideSelector) view.findViewById(R.id.side_selector);
        adapter = new LibraryListAdapter();
        itemsView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        itemsView.setAdapter(adapter);
        /*itemsView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int visiblePos = ((LinearLayoutManager)itemsView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                int section = adapter.getSectionForPosition(visiblePos);
                selector.setCurrentSection(section);
            }
        });

        selector.setView(itemsView);*/

        mDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(getContext().getApplicationContext(),
                AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();

        setMenu();

        return view;
    }

    public void setSongs(String title) {
        adapter.clearList();
        mTitle.setText(title);
        selector.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        getSongs();
    }

    public void setMenu() {
        ArrayList<ListItem> data = new ArrayList<>();
        mTitle.setText("LIBRARY");

        data.add(new MenuInfo(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setSongs("ALL");
            }
        }, "All"));
        data.add(new MenuInfo(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setSongs("MUSIC & MUSICALS");
            }
        }, "Music & Musicals"));
        data.add(new MenuInfo(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setSongs("MOVIES & TELEVISION");
            }
        }, "Movies & Television"));
        data.add(new MenuInfo(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setSongs("HISTORY & LITERATURE");
            }
        }, "History & Literature"));

        selector.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adapter.setListItems(data);
    }

    private void getSongs() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Song>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<Song> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                final Song.Dao songDao = mDatabase.songDao();
                return songDao.getAll();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<Song> songs) {
                for (Song song : songs) {
                    adapter.addListItem(new MediaInfo(song));
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }.execute();
    }

}
```

*Adapter*

```
public class LibraryListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements SectionIndexer {

    public static String[] ALPHABET = new String[]{"#", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
            "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

    private List<ListItem> mDataArray = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

    public void setListItems(List<ListItem> items) {
        mDataArray = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addListItem(ListItem item) {
        mDataArray.add(item);
    }

    public void clearList() {
        mDataArray.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void notifyChange() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(mDataArray.size() > position && position >= 0) {
            return mDataArray.get(position).getType();
        }

        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        int section = 0;
        if(mDataArray.size() > position && position >= 0) {
            for(String letter : ALPHABET) {
                if(mDataArray.get(position).getName().startsWith(letter)) {
                    break;
                }
                section++;
            }
        }

        return section;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        return ALPHABET;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int sectionIndex) {
        if(sectionIndex < 0) { sectionIndex = 0; }
        if(sectionIndex >= ALPHABET.length) { sectionIndex = ALPHABET.length - 1; }

        int position = 0;
        for (ListItem info : mDataArray) {
            if(info instanceof MediaInfo) {
                if (((MediaInfo) info).getName().charAt(0) >= ALPHABET[sectionIndex].charAt(0)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            position++;
        }

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View item = null;

        switch (viewType) {
            case ListItem.VIEW_TYPE_MEDIA:
                item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.library_media_item, parent, false);
                return new MediaItemViewHolder(item);
            case ListItem.VIEW_TYPE_MENU_ITEM:
                item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.library_menu_item, parent, false);
                return new MenuItemViewHolder(item);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(mDataArray.get(position).getOnClickListener());

        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case ListItem.VIEW_TYPE_MEDIA:
                MediaItemViewHolder holder_media = (MediaItemViewHolder) holder;
                holder_media.setTitle(mDataArray.get(position).getName());
                holder_media.setArtist(((MediaInfo) mDataArray.get(position)).getSong().getArtist());
                holder_media.setType(((MediaInfo) mDataArray.get(position)).getSong().getMode());
                break;
            case ListItem.VIEW_TYPE_MENU_ITEM:
                MenuItemViewHolder holder_menu = (MenuItemViewHolder) holder;
                holder_menu.setName(mDataArray.get(position).getName());
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataArray.size();
    }

    public static class MediaItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mTitleView;
        public TextView mArtistView;
        public ImageView mImageView;

        public MediaItemViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v); // done this way instead of view tagging
            mTitleView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.library_item_title);
            mArtistView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.library_item_artist);
            mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.library_item_icon);
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            mTitleView.setText(title);
        }

        public void setArtist(String artist) {
            mArtistView.setText(artist);
        }

        public void setType(Song.ModeType type) {
            switch (type) {
                case BOOK:
                    mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_book);
                    break;
                case MOVIE:
                    mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_movie);
                    break;
                case SONG:
                    mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_music);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MenuItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mNameView;

        public MenuItemViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v); // done this way instead of view tagging
            mNameView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            mNameView.setText(name);
        }
    }
}
```

*Layout*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="35dp"
    android:paddingRight="35dp"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/library_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/side_selector"
            android:background="@drawable/border_top_gray"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <com.beneville.grandfatherclock.views.SideSelector
            android:id="@+id/side_selector"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove `jquery` tag :)

Comment: oops don't know how that got in there

Comment: not pretty sure but you can try `itemsView.setHasFixedSize(true)` before `setLayoutManager` and `setAdapter`

Comment: Still happens with setHasFixedItemSize. I may just start from scratch using a ListView instead of RecyclerView.

Comment: I still prefer RecyclerView instead of List, but doesn't harm to try. Will try to create a simple app, to see whether having same issue

Answer (score 0):

The choppy scrolling in Android is the app taking too much time on the main application thread updating the UI. In the case of RecyclerView, this would mean taking too much time in onBindViewHolder() or possibly in onCreateViewHolder().

Here is a good read on ways to make your scrolling smooth as butter: [6 ways to make your Android app scroll faster than the wind](https://leftshift.io/6-ways-to-make-your-lists-scroll-faster-than-the-wind)

Comment: I would say that I'm already doing all of these. I'm using RecyclerView and not ListView so I don't have a getView() but my view creation is not complex. I use the ViewHolder pattern already. Even if I get rid of my 3 small icons it doesn't fix it. My views themselves are only 2 TextViews, cant get much simpler than that. The article mentions setting some cache properties which didn't change anything.

Comment: Choppy might have been a poor word choice, its not that it stutters as it scroll but just completely stops like it reached the bottom of the list.